# When was H-alpha first used to observe the universe?

Tags: observational-astronomy, history, h-alpha

The H-alpha line is used by astronomers to trace the presence of hydrogen in galaxies or to view protuberances on the Sun. When was the H-alpha emission of astronomical objects such as galaxies first observed ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's surprisingly hard to research this, partly because the name "H-alpha" only became common towards the end of the 19th Century, and partly because (I get the impression) a lot of mid- and late-19th Century spectroscopy ignored the red end of the spectrum, perhaps because the equipment was less sensitive there. Thus, you can find a fair amount of discussion from the late 19th Century about emission lines from nebulae which are focused on the blue region of the spectrum, with a mysterious line near 5005 or 5006 Angstrom (what we now know is [O III] 5007) referred to as the "principal line", and no mention of H-alpha at all.

Nevertheless, it seems pretty clear that [Huggins & Miller observed H-alpha in emission from the 1866 outburst](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rspl.1866.0036) of the recurrent nova [T Corona Borealis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T_Coronae_Borealis) -- they noted the appearance of a bright line near or at "Fraunhofer's C" line (the old name for H-alpha), and referred to its association with hydrogen as "extremely probable". (Even clearer is an emission line at the location of "Fraunhofer's F" line, which is H-beta.) I think this might qualify as the first real astronomical observation of H-alpha in emission.

The earliest observation of H-alpha in emission from the Sun was by the French scientist [Pierre Janssen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Janssen) in 1868, during an eclipse of the Sun, when he passed the light from the solar corona through a spectrograph and recorded the spectrum on a photographic plate. (He also observed a mystery emission line that turned out to be the first evidence for helium.)

Answer (score 4):

Seemingly easy question, but actually not trivial to answer.

[Wikipedia on H-alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-alpha) as well as other entries in other encyclopedias obviously mention the [Balmer series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balmer_series) and that the spectral line was discovered by [Johann Balmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Jakob_Balmer) in 1885, but that does not answer your question about the first astronomical observation. The [article on the Balmer jump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balmer_jump) cites a [publication as early as 1957](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balmer_jump), but I am doubtful whether that is really the first publication on the topic.

Using [google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=H+alpha%2CH%CE%B1%2Cbalmer%2Clyman&year_start=1880&year_end=2000&corpus=26&smoothing=3) on a book-standard [corpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_corpus) as oracle, you could obtain pictures as the following:
[image: ngram graph]

There is no prominent peak for any of the keywords `lyman`, `H alpha`, or `balmer`  which might support my hypothesis, that the first (astronomical) use of Balmer's discovery before mid 1950. However, I cannot explain the two maxima of the (blue) `H alpha` line (pun intended) in the ngram time series.